# OpenMP Ordered Parallelization

Tags: c++, openmp, parallel-processing

I'm trying to parallelize the following function (pseudocode):

```
vector<int32> out;
for (int32 i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int32 result = multiplyStuffByTwo(i);

    // Push to results
    out.push_back(result);
}
```

When I now parallelize the for loop and define the push_back part as a critical path, I'm encountering the problem that (of course) the order of the results in out is not always right. How can I make the threads run execute the code in the right order in the last line of the for loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the size of the out-vector by calling out.resize() and then set the value by index, not by push_back()

Pseudo-code:

```cpp
vector<int32> out; out.resize(10);
for (int32 i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   int32 result = multiplyStuffByTwo(i);

   // set the result
   out[i] = result;
}
```

But, I'd recommend using "classic" arrays. They're much faster and not really harder to manage

Comment: Thank you! I will try that today - when using vector, do I need to set a thread lock (critical area) on the write process?

Comment: Actually, in general the vector class is not thread-safe. Thats why push_back() is very problematic. But in this case I don't expect any problems. Once again: Better use a normal array for such simple operations (and if you don't need a resizable container)

Comment: Why would you expect "classic" arrays to be any faster, once you've moved the resize out of the loop?  They should be identical.

Comment: You are right, I thought, operator[] would throw an exception when the index out of range. But only at() throws. So, there actually shouldnt be any performance issue here.

Comment: So the new problem is that the loop becomes slower now as (I think) with every write in out, the other core's caches are invalidated. I could think of using a private out for every thread and then interleaving it, but OpenMP only allows reduction with primitive operations like */+/-, but no assignment. Does anyone have a hint about that? Thanks!

Comment: No, as long as you dont set some kind of blocking mechanism, the writing does not slow down the operation. Remember that creating threads is *not* zero-cost and that you will need a iteration count high enough (even 100 may be very low, depending on your calculations) to get a benefit with openmp. Did you also set the number of threads?

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int32> out;

#pragma omp parallel for ordered 
for (int32 i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int32 result = multiplyStuffByTwo(i); // this will be run in parallel

    #pragma omp ordered
    // Push to results
    out.push_back(result); // this will be run sequential
}
```

This can be helpful:

http://openmp.org/mp-documents/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf

Comment: -1: If you add that pragma you lose the parallelisation, which was the whole point.

Comment: Thanks, I also checked that before and the execution times goes up because of the thread handling necessary.

Comment: @Jørgen Fogh: right, I corrected the snippet; now, only vector operation is serial, and `multiplyStuffByTwo` is done in parallel. If this operation would last long, you should gain here.